# Not getting application icon if not installed in device?

Tags: android

I have an app in which i want to get application icon from package name. I am using code as mentioned below but it doen't work when app is not installed in device. Pls help me out.

code:-

```
 Drawable applicationIcon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("com.whatsapp");
        tvWhatsapp.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, applicationIcon, null, null);
```

Comment: Why do you think you can get an application's icon if it isn't installed? Of course this doesn't work. The app is not installed! Therefore, the icon is not on your device.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do...

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Indeed

Comment: I just trying to get app icon doesn't matter app is install or not

Comment: @Niraj If the app is not installed, where do you get the icon from?

Comment: Ah seriously, let us know if there is work around of it also @Niraj

Comment: if you can't find it, you can't get it. You need a different approach other than using your package manager. @Niraj

Comment: Then what is that approach

Comment: use this 
Drawable icon = getPackageManager().getApplicationIcon("org.telegram.messenger");

Comment: I did the same pls see my code

Answer (score 2):

Getting the app icon by using package manager, it is necessary to have the app installed on your device.